# How to calculate missing corners of rectangle based on the length to width ratio

Tags: python, geometry, algebra

I need to calculate in Python coordinates of the remaining vertices of the rectangle `P3 = (x3, y3)` and `P4 = (x4, y4)`, knowing its two opposite vertices (`P1` and `P2`) and the lengths of the sides of the rectangle (like below).

[image]

Where:

```
P1 = (6.237204, 51.071833)
P2 = (6.237195, 51.071836)
```

Based on this, I know that the ratio between length and width is 1/94.

I have the impression that more arithmetic calculations are needed here and unfortunately I am stuck at this point. Is someone able to help?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: This seems like more of a maths question than a programming question.

Comment: Is rectangle axis-aligned? Are coordinates really lat/lon? How 8 millimeters corresponds to difference of 6.23... values or 51.07.. values?

Answer (score 0):

The diagonal P1P2 makes an angle equal to twice the arc tangent of 1/94 with the other diagonal and they cross in their middle.

Using a polar coordinate system centered at that middle, you can compute the azimuth of P4, add the above angle and convert P2 back to Cartesian.